# Calculate card at hand

Tags: javascript

The code is supposed to create a function that computes and return the score for the cards by adding the values of all the cards in hand. The eight or fewer cards at hand should be randomly selected from the 52 array elements. However, the value of a Jack, Queen, or King is 10.

I have been able to iterate through the cards and randomly selected 8 cards. I am, however, unable to replace the value of Jack, King, and Queen with 10 for each occurrence.

```
function showHand(){
    var suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs'];
    var cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'];
    var deal = [];
    for(suit in suits){
        for(card in cards){
            deal.push(cards[card]);
        }
     }
     var handCard = deal.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deal.length), 8);
     var getGolfScore = golfScore(handCard);

     document.getElementById('dvShowHand').innerHTML = list + '<br>' + getGolfScore;
 }

function golfScore(hand){
    var sumCardInHand = 0;
    for(hands in hand){ 
        if(hand[hands] == 'Jack' || hand[hands] == 'King' || hand[hands] == 'Queen'){ 
        hand[hands] = 10; 
         }              
         sumCardInHand += hand[hands];
     }
     return sumCardInHand;
 }
```

For example, if the hand were this array: [5, 2, "King", 3, 1, "Queen"], the
golfScore function would return 31.

Comment: The function works

Comment: Your `for` statement is confusing. The singular and plural variable names are reversed. `hands` should probably be `card`.

Comment: Noted. I will correct that.